# Can't copy ABI on new remix

Tags: ethereum, remix

I have been trying to copy the ABI of my contract but when I copy and paste it, what I see is "[ ]". Please help

Comment: You'll have to provide more information to help reproduce your issue. Maybe include the contract you're trying to generate the ABI for. Also, you can try generating it using solc: `solc MyContract.sol --abi -o OUTPUT_DIR`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in Google Chrome. This issue resolved itself by changing the browser to Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I have the problem in Firefox :/